# FFMPEG: Specifying Output Stream Type When Combing Multiple Filters

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I currently have 3 separate `ffmpeg` commands that do the following:

1. Overlay a watermark on a video: `ffmpeg -i samplegreen.webm -i foregrounds/myimage.png -r 30 -filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h" -af "adelay=700" output.mp4`
2. Overlay the results of 1) onto a beach video: `ffmpeg -i backgrounds/beachsunsetmp4.mp4 -i output.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]chromakey=0x005d0b:0.1485:0.03[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[o]" -map [o] -map 1:a -shortest somefolder/sample_video.mp4`
3. Merge the audio of the results of 2) with another audio file: `ffmpeg -i somefolder/sample_video.mp4 -i backgrounds/beachsunsetmp4.mp3 -filter_complex '[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]' -map 0:v -map '[a]' -c:v copy -ac 2 -shortest anotherfolder/sample_video.mp4`

Now, this all works as intended, however, I was looking into attempting to combine them all into a single command, combining all the filters, like so:

```
ffmpeg -i samplegreen.webm -i foregrounds/myimage.png -r 30 -i backgrounds/beachsunsetmp4.mp4 -i backgrounds/beachsunsetmp4.mp3 -filter_complex \
    "[0]overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h[output_1]; \
     [output_1]chromakey=0x005d0b:0.1485:0.03[ckout]; \
     [2:v][ckout]overlay[output_2]; \
     [output_2][3:a] amerge=inputs=2 [output_3]" \
    -af "adelay=700" -map [output_3] shortest final.mp4
```

It fails with the following error (`Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_overlay_2' filter output pad 0 (video) and the 'Parsed_amerge_3' filter input pad 0 (audio)`):

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.2_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'samplegreen.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
Input #1, png_pipe, from 'foregrounds/myimage.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 350x86, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'backgrounds/beachsunsetmp4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2021-02-16T18:24:40.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:32.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3032 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 3027 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-02-16T18:24:40.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
[mp3 @ 0x7f86cf809000] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #3, mp3, from 'backgrounds/beachsunsetmp4.mp3':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2021-02-18 06:49
    id3v2_priv.XMP  : <?xpacket begin="\xef\xbb\xbf" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>\x0a<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 6.0-c003 79.164527, 2020/10/15-17:48:32        ">\x0a <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">\x0a  <rdf
  Duration: 00:00:32.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 132 kb/s
    Stream #3:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
[Parsed_overlay_2 @ 0x7f86cd4039c0] Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_overlay_2' filter output pad 0 (video) and the 'Parsed_amerge_3' filter input pad 0 (audio)
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f86cd402a40] Cannot create the link overlay:0 -> amerge:0
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

As far as I can tell, the issue is that the filter, `amerge`, wants 2 audio streams. Normally, I could take the input stream argument (which is a video), and make it use the audio by doing something like `[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[results]`. However, since my input stream is the output of a preceding filter, that doesn't seem to work (i.e. [output_2:a]). It bombs out with:

```
[matroska,webm @ 0x7fecca000000] Invalid stream specifier: output_2:a.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Stream specifier 'output_2:a' in filtergraph description [0]overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h[output_1];      [output_1]chromakey=0x005d0b:0.1485:0.03[ckout];      [2:v][ckout]overlay[output_2];      [output_2:a][3:a] amerge=inputs=2 [output_3] matches no streams.
```

So all of that said... Is there a way to specify that I'd like to use the audio stream from the output of a preceding filter? Or any other ways to combine all of these filters into a single command?

Thanks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Except for a few filters like concat, a filter will take either only video inputs or only audio.

---

Here's the combined command.

```
ffmpeg \
 -i samplegreen.webm \
 -i foregrounds/myimage.png \
 -i backgrounds/beachsunsetmp4.mp4 \
 -i backgrounds/beachsunsetmp4.mp3 \
 -filter_complex \
 "[0][1]overlay=(W-w)/2:H-h,chromakey=0x005d0b:0.1485:0.03[ckout]; \
  [2][ckout]overlay=shortest=1[v]; \
  [0]adelay=700:all=1[0a]; \
  [0a][3]amerge=inputs=2[a]" \
 -map '[v]' -map '[a]' \
 -shortest -r 30 -ac 2 \
output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you for this! The only issue now is, the video length is 33s long, whereas when executing all the commands separately, it's only 13s long. Any ideas? And thank you for the quick response, this really helps me out a lot!

Comment: Modified final overlay

Comment: Sorry for late response, bu that worked! Thanks again!